# How to refresh all contents of a frame in java awt

Tags: java, awt

I'm writing a basic decision map game where you can choose between 2 options and depending on the option you choose you will move to a different node with another 2 options etc.

I have the code running in the shell but am trying to get it running in an `AWT GUI`, I have a very basic window with 2 buttons with the two options but I can't get the page to refresh after clicking a button. Is there a good way to do this?

My code is below:

```
import java.awt.*; //Imports all from AWT library
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class UI extends Frame implements ActionListener {
    DecisionMap DM;
    DecisionNode DMnode;
    Label description;
    Label option1;
    Label option2;

    public void GUI() throws FileNotFoundException {

        DM = new DecisionMap();
        DMnode = DM.entryPoint();

        // set the description given for the node, above the buttons
        Label description = new Label(DMnode.getDescription());
        description.setBounds(10,50,700,45);
        add(description);

        // sets frame size and makes it visible
        setSize(1200,800);
        setLayout(null);
        setVisible(true);


        //1st option button
        Button B1=new Button(DMnode.getoption1());
        B1.setBounds(150,250,800,40);// setting button position
        add(B1);//adding button into frame
        B1.setSize(900,100);//frame size 300 width and 300 height

        //2nd option button
        Button B2=new Button(DMnode.getoption2());
        B2.setBounds(150,400,800,40);// setting button position
        add(B2);//adding button into frame
        B2.setSize(900,100);//frame size 300 width and 300 height




        //Waits for button to be clicked and refreshes window to new node
        B1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
                DecisionNode node = DM.entryPoint();
                Scanner Input = new Scanner(System.in);

                while (node != null){
                    node = node.getYesNode();

                }
            }
        }
        );

        B2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
                DecisionNode node = DM.entryPoint();
                Scanner Input = new Scanner(System.in);

                while (node != null){
                    node = node.getNoNode();
                }

            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        
    }
}
```

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) Java GUIs have to work on different OS', screen size, screen resolution etc.  using different PLAFs in different locales.  As such, they are not conducive to pixel perfect layout.  Instead use layout managers, or [combinations of them](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556) along with layout padding and borders for [white space](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17874718/418556). 3) Why use AWT?   See ..

Comment: .. [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6255106/java-gui-listeners-without-awt/6255978#6255978) for many good reasons to abandon AWT components in favor of Swing. 4) Please learn common Java nomenclature (naming conventions - e.g. `EachWordUpperCaseClass`, `firstWordLowerCaseMethod()`, `firstWordLowerCaseAttribute` unless it is an `UPPER_CASE_CONSTANT`) and use it consistently.